# swift share extension with 4 file types

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i want to make a shareExtenion that can share this type of files:

vCard - max 1 item
images - max 5 items
video - max 5 items
text - max 1 items
url - max 1 items

i use this code in NSExtensionAttribute:

```
SUBQUERY (
extensionItems,
$extensionItem,
SUBQUERY (
    $extensionItem.attachments,
    $attachment,
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard"
).@count == 1 || 
SUBQUERY (
    $extensionItem.attachments,
    $attachment,
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
).@count < 6 || 
SUBQUERY (
    $extensionItem.attachments,
    $attachment,
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.video"
).@count < 6 ||
SUBQUERY (
    $extensionItem.attachments,
    $attachment,
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
).@count == 1 ||
SUBQUERY (
    $extensionItem.attachments,
    $attachment,
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
).@count == 1
).@count == 1
```

The problem is that the extension is visible in other file type example .doc or .pdf and the limit of < 6 does not work!

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you solved it?

Comment: Not solved, and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text").@count >= 1).@count >= 1
            OR SUBQUERY(extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, SUBQUERY($attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers, $uti, $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" AND NOT $uti UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url").@count >= 1).@count >= 1).@count >= 1
            OR SUBQUERY(extensionItems,$extensionItem,SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments,$attachment,ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image").@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 5).@count == 1
            OR SUBQUERY(extensionItems,$extensionItem,SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments,$attachment,ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie").@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 5).@count == 1
            OR SUBQUERY(extensionItems,$extensionItem,SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments,$attachment,ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.content").@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 1).@count == 1
            </string>
    </dict>
```